# adminMongo expiration date for coupon

Tags: json

It's the first time am using adminMongo, and I have to manage a online shop with existing coupons database on the adminMongo, who are made for that shop.

I have already a coupon code:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5f3e29af05c44a7e68a55af0"),
    "name": "ZRTEST",
    "type": "percent",
    "discount": 10,
    "freeShipping": false,
    "products": [
        "any"
    ],
}
```

and I want to add a string where I can set up the expiration (validity) date for this coupon, can someone help me please?

Comment: Are you just looking to add it manually or by JS code?

Comment: manually, just on the bottom after everything else

Comment: Could just add a [timestamp](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/)?

Comment: OK, but can you please tell me how to insert correctly the generated timestamp into my code?

Comment: `"expiration": 1597913040`. I haven't used adminMongo but it looks like you just add it as a key/value pair in the GUI

Comment: That actually do not change anything, I set yesterday as date, and is still valid right now.

Comment: It wouldn't make it invalid, you'd have to do that yourself with JS code. There is a way to set a TTL on the data but I've never used it. [Check it out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/) though, might be useful for you.